# ocgx2 package: printed links have low resolution

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links, doi, ocgx2

I encountered a weird behavior when using the ocgx2 package. It allows one to have colored links (like urls, but also references to sections in the toc, basically everything clickable) in the pdf but when printed the links are black. However, I noticed that when printed all the links appear thicker than the normal text. I then "printed" a pdf using Microsoft Print to PDF and I then saw this:
[image]

The MWE is here

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{links}{RGB}{0,128,172}
\usepackage[% hidelinks,
                colorlinks=true,
                urlcolor=links,    % color of external links
                linkcolor=links,  % color of toc, list of figs etc.
                citecolor=links,
                hypertexnames = false,
                hyperfootnotes = true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\label{introduction}

This document shows the ocgx2 Bug I encountered. See the printed "Introduction" link in the table of contents.

\end{document}
```

The link in the "printed" pdf has a low resolution while the original link appears to be normal.

Comment: Which document class do you use? When I use 'book' the blue 'Introduction' is less sharp than when I use 'article'.

Comment: @riloban Did you print from within Acrobat Reader?

Comment: HI! I actually use the scrreprt class, and I encountered the bug there, I just used the article class just for the MWE. And yes, I print the pdf using Acrobat Reader.